# Data schema best practices involving .Net Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I'm working on an MVC 3 application using .NET membership and using Entity Framework for data access.  I'm fairly new at using these technologies.  I keep on running into hangups when I'm trying to relate application data to specific users.

So let's say you have a user that was created with .NET Membership Provider and as that user you create certain application objects that should be tied specifically to that user.  Each user would access their own list of these objects.  I'm curious what the best practice would be.  I need to create a foreign key on these applications objects so I know that they belong to a certain user.  I'm just not sure what that value should be.

Also, let's say you have an admin user that can see all of these application objects for each user and what user they belong to?  Using Entity Framework I would like to be able to run such a query.  But you don't generally have entities that represent the membership objects.

Hopefully I'm illustrating my confusion well enough.  Please let me know if I'm being unclear.  Any help anyone can give on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I develop an application that goes beyond what the .NET Membership Provider offers I create my own tables in the application database for users, user profiles, and roles.  This will give you flexibility in designing the information you want to maintain on the users and then you can use EF to access that information.  What EF approach are you using; is it code-first, model-first, or database-first?  If you are using code-first EF will create the relationships for you by creating object ID's of type int in the DB that are set to "Is Identity" and self increment. You can override this by using attributes on properties on your objects like this:

```
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
```

Using int's provides for more efficient indexing but Guid's are beneficial if you are using replicated or distributed databases. You can use either option for maintaining relationships between objects if you are using the model-first or database-first approaches.  By using the concept of object ID's instead of using other primary keys give the user the ability to change user information without messing up an table relations.  For example, if the primary key for the user table is the user name and the user decides to change their user name you would then have to update all of the foreign keys as well.

By moving the membership information into your application you will have a lot more flexibility in defining the membership information and the relationship between other application entities, which in turn will allow you to perform the queries you are looking for.